# what Return: means in Go

Tags: go

I came across a function like this (simplified for clarity):

```golang
func myfunc(ir io.RuneReader, ib []byte, is string, pos, ncap int, dstCap []int) []int {
var matched bool
// do something to get matched, change dstCap
Return:
    if !matched {
        return nil
    }
    return dstCap
}
```

What the line 'Return:' means?

Comment: It's a label: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Labeled_statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [label](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Labeled_statements). It can be used as the target of a `goto`, `break`, or `continue` statement.